Custom verbatim environment affects quotation marks
I have a custom verbatim environment that changes color to red, but creates problems with quotation marks. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newverbs}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\color{red}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\color{red}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{verbatim}
        "I
    \end{verbatim}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}

I get the following:

If you comment the new environment verbatim works find, but in black colour. How can I keep my environment without messing up the rest?

Unrelated to the question, but you don't need \usetheme{default}, like the name says, that's the default.

If you goal is just to turn verbatim red and you don't need more complicated changes you don't need any packages and can simply use LaTeX's hook mechanism.
Note that the normal kernel verbatim has no leading space stripping mechanism, so the following is more indented than in my other answer because verbatim is indented.
\documentclass{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\AddToHook{env/verbatim/begin}{\color{red}}
\RenewDocumentCommand\verb{v}{\textcolor{red}{\frenchspacing\ttfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{verbatim}
        "I
    \end{verbatim}
    
    \verb|a"Ibc|
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks! I like this simpler option. Out of curiosity, do you know WHY this is happening?

Why what is happening?

why redefining the environment messes up the quotation marks

@luchonacho Because " is turned active by \usepackage[spanish]{babel} and defined to mean the next character should get diacritic two overdots, and the \semiverbatim reading doesn't prevent that from happening.

There are definitely other and perhaps better (for instance fancyvrb has the formatcom key to which you could pass \color{red}, only difference is you'd use Verbatim instead of verbatim), but the following uses enverb (disclaimer: I'm the author of enverb) to collect the contents of the verbatim environment and uses the original verbatim definition to typeset the output (but you can add whatever code you want to alter it around \enverbListing{verbatim}{}, even things that take arguments work).
I made the redefinition of \verb using \NewDocumentCommand.
enverb detects the amount of indentation the matching \end-block has and automatically removes this much leading characters from the body (turn this off using the auto-ignore=false option) plus an additional 2 characters (you can change this by setting more-ignore=0 for instance).
\documentclass{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{enverb}

% make a copy of the normal verbatim environment
\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldVerbatim}{verbatim}
\renewenvironment{verbatim}
  {\enverb{}}
  {%
    \color{red}%
    % locally get the normal verbatim back
    \DeclareEnvironmentCopy{verbatim}{oldVerbatim}%
    \enverbListing{verbatim}{}%
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand\verb{v}{\textcolor{red}{\frenchspacing\ttfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{verbatim}
        "I
    \end{verbatim}
    
    \verb|a"Ibc|
\end{frame}

\end{document}


